# Powershell: how to get rid of CMD output while assigning a variable (nslookup)

Tags: powershell, redirect, cmd, ip, nslookup

I want to run nslookup in a powershell script, assigning the output to a string variable I can parse up. I don't want to see echos like "Non-authoritative answer:" in the powershell window from the CMD execution, but everything I have tried to pipe or redirect the output of the command exclusively to the variable have not worked or broken the variable.

Example:

```
PS> $temp = (& nslookup 'myip.opendns.com','resolver1.opendns.com');
Non-authoritative answer:
```

I've tried several work-arounds...

```
PS> $temp = Invoke-Expression "cmd /c nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com" >$null

PS> $temp = Invoke-Expression "cmd /c @ECHO off && nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com"
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this. The way I'm working with a string here just to get the IP address is a few more lines than I'd like.

```
$temp = (nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com) | Out-String
$temp = $temp.split()
$tempIPs = $temp -match "^(.|\r|\n)*?\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b"
$publicIP = $tempIPs[1]
return $PublicIP
```

I've gone this route because using two servers, like I'm doing with nslookup, doesn't seem to work with powershell's Resolve-DnsName command. I need the two servers because I'm redirecting the lookup to get my public IP. There are other ways to do that, but this one works really well and `(invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip).Content` has glitched out on me while working on this script.

Comment: That doesn't work in this case. I would love to skip old CMD files, but like I mentioned in the last paragraph, I haven't found a purely powershell way to do it with 2 servers. I tried the command in our post and it complains that "No such host in known". ... I swear I'm not talking to myself. There was another comment here and now it's gone. O.o

Comment: You can redirect error messages to null like this  `nslookup "myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com  2>out-null `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the server to resolve your query against by specifying the `-Server` parameter of `Resolve-DnsName`.

```
Resolve-DnsName -Name myip.opendns.com -Server resolver1.opendns.com
```

From the [MSDN documentation](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=287336) for the `Resolve-DnsName` command:

> -Server <String[]>
>       Specifies the IP addresses or host names of the DNS servers to be queried. By default the interface DNS servers are queried if this parameter is not supplied.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the command up, I somehow thought I was trying to resolve a server to another server and I didn't know one of them needed to be specified as a name. Now that I see it, it makes sense.